# Flutter : Mongo Dart Plugin is not working

Tags: dart, flutter

i want to use mongo to store my app data, but when ever i try to `await db.open()` this error appear on the console:

```
[ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (11408): type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<bool>' where
E/flutter (11408):   Future is from dart:async
E/flutter (11408):   Future is from dart:async
E/flutter (11408):   bool is from dart:core
E/flutter (11408):
E/flutter (11408): #0      _Connection.connect (file:///C:/Users/Picmix/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mongo_dart-0.3.1/lib/src/network/connection.dart:73:22)
E/flutter (11408): #1      _ConnectionManager._connect (file:///C:/Users/Picmix/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mongo_dart-0.3.1/lib/src/network/connection_manager.dart:23:22)
E/flutter (11408): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11408): #2      _ConnectionManager.open.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/Users/Picmix/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mongo_dart-0.3.1/lib/src/network/connection_manager.dart:58:14)
E/flutter (11408): #3      Future.forEach.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:484:26)
E/flutter (11408): #4      Future.doWhile.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:526:26)
E/flutter (11408): #5      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1316:10)
E/flutter (11408): #6      _RootZone.bindUnaryCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1355:26)
E/flutter (11408): #7      Future.doWhile (dart:async/future.dart:541:18)
E/flutter (11408): #8      Future.forEach (dart:async/future.dart:482:12)
E/flutter (11408): #9      _ConnectionManager.open (file:///C:/Users/Picmix/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mongo_dart-0.3.1/lib/src/network/connection_manager.dart:56:19)
E/flutter (11408): #10     Db.open.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/Users/Picmix/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mongo_dart-0.3.1/lib/src/database/db.dart:252:33)
E/flutter (11408): #11     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:222:31)
E/flutter (11408): #12     Db.open (file:///C:/Users/Picmix/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mongo_dart-0.3.1/lib/src/database/db.dart:239:16)
E/flutter (11408): #13     main (file:///F:/Jamil/WORKSHOP/MY-PRACTICE/FLUTTER/FLUTTERMONGO/simplecrud/lib/main.dart:6:6)
E/flutter (11408): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11408): #14     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:279:19)
E/flutter (11408): #15     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:165:12)
E/flutter (11408): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (11408): type '(MongoReplyMessage) => void' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => void'
E/flutter (11408): #0      _rootHandleUncaughtError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1114:29)
E/flutter (11408): #1      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
E/flutter (11408): #2      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
```

and this is the simple code that i write to open connection between mlab and the app:

```
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart';

void main() async {
  print('hello');
  Db db = new Db('mongodb://<myusername><mypassword>@ds147659.mlab.com:47659/simple-crud');
  db.open().then((success) {
    if (success) print('connected');
  });
}
```

any idea sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the latest flutter update beta2.
Please check this [blog by flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-io/https-medium-com-flutter-io-announcing-flutters-beta-2-c85ba1557d5e)

Seems like there is a flutter version mismatch of your project and Mongo plugin.

Mongo's latest plugin was updated on Oct 24, 2017.

There is already an [issue on their git](https://github.com/mongo-dart/mongo_dart/issues/124). You can keep track of it.

Meanwhile, according to [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15654):
you can try changing the plugin code from

```
Future<bool> get isOn => _channel.invokeMethod('isOn');
```

to

```
Future<bool> get isOn async {
 final bool isOn = await _channel.invokeMethod('isOn');
 return isOn;
}
```

**NOTE**: Above is just an example, please check the plugin dart file for the correct function to change.